# Random elements in probability

Tags: probability

How many 5 digit numbers are there where

a) all digits are non-zero,

b) all digits are different, and

c) the digits appear in increasing order

E.g., 12345 and 25679 satisfy the conditions but 25367 and 20934 do not.

I thought that the answer would be $$ 10 * 9 * 8* 7 *6 $$

However, I was told that once I pick the subset of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} that will appear as digits, thus there's something else I need to determine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you asking for all of these conditions to be satisfied simultaneously?  Or are you asking each of these as separate questions?  What do you know about the [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)?  In how many ways can you arrange five specific distinct numbers so that they are in increasing order?

Comment: The number $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ is the number of $5$-digit numbers not subject to the increasing condition.

Comment: To pick $5$ distinct digits (where all digits are non zero): there are $9\times8\times7\times6\times5$ possibilities. Once you have picked them, there's only one possibility to write them in increasing order; yet there are $5!$ possibilities to order them… can you figure out what you need to do?

Comment: @JMoravitz no it's one question.

Comment: Would it be (9 choose 5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply (*a very short application of*) Multiplication Principle:

- Pick the digits used in the number
- Arrange these digits in increasing order

> The first step may be completed in $\binom{9}{5}$ ways since we are looking for a subset of five digits from the set of available digits $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$.  The second step may only be done in **one** way.  The final answer being then $\binom{9}{5}$

Compare this to the question of how many five-digit numbers without zeroes with all distinct digits have their smallest digit at the front.  E.g. $26359$ and $49876$ are both good while $52894$ is not.

> Pick the five digits used, and then pick the order in which they appear.  In picking the order, the location of the smallest is predetermined to be the front, but the remaining four can be arranged in $4!$ many ways, for a total of $\binom{9}{5}4!$